# take the last one id in dataframe using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

how i select row in dataframe based on the last position for every user id. Is there any idea?

```
data=pd.DataFrame({'User_ID':['122','122','122','233','233','233','233','366','366','366'],'Age':[23,23,np.nan,24,24,24,24,21,21,np.nan]})
```

data

and the outcomes should be like this

```
data_new=pd.DataFrame({'User_ID':['122','233','366'],'Age':[np.nan,24,np.nan]})
```

so i just try to take the last row for every user_id. I'm totally beginner, is there any idea?

Comment: `data.drop_duplicates(subset='User_ID', keep='last')`

Answer (score 0):

As you want to keep the NaN, you can [`groupby.tail`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html) (`groupby.last` would drop the NaNs):

```
out = data.groupby('User_ID').tail(1)
```

Another option is to [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
out = data.drop_duplicates(subset='User_ID', keep='last')
```

output:

```
  User_ID   Age
2     122   NaN
6     233  24.0
9     366   NaN
```

If you want to reset the index in the process use `ignore_index=True`:

```
out =  data.drop_duplicates(subset='User_ID', keep='last', ignore_index=True)
```

output:

```
  User_ID   Age
0     122   NaN
1     233  24.0
2     366   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data_new =data.drop_duplicates(subset='User_ID', keep='last')
```